# How to concatenate to collections in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I use the following code.

`Collection<MyClass> MyCollection1 = new Collection<MyClass>();
 MyCollection.Concat(GetSecondCollcetion());`

No matter what function `GetSecondCollcetion()` returns(Obviously Object of `Collection<MyClass>`) the `MyCollection1` Always Empty. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (if you don't explicitly **need** MyCollection to be a variable of `Collection<MyClass>`:

```
var MyCollection1 = new Collection<MyClass>().Concat(GetSecondCollcetion());
```

Alternatively

```
Collection<MyClass> MyCollection1 = new Collection<MyClass>(GetSecondCollection());
```

Or as @Cine says:

```
MyCollection.AddRange(GetSecondCollcetion());
```

Comment: Or if the collection supports it (like List) then AddRange is a good function

Comment: There is no implicit conversion when is use explicit conversion it shows `Unable to cast object of type '<ConcatIterator>d__71`1[MyClass]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[MyClass]'.`

Comment: Ahh.. but of course, since Concat() returns an IEnumerable<MyClass>, then as Cine says, you can always use AddRange() if it is a "multi-step" build up.

Comment: But `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection` doen't support `AddRange()`

Comment: It is just a shorthand for a loop over the items in one collection calling Add on the other...

Answer (score 1):

The Linq method [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) doesn't change the first collection, it returns a new (third) collection with the result: the combination of the two input collections.

So use:

```
MyCollection1 = MyCollection1.Concat(GetSecondCollcetion()).ToList();
```

Or use AddRange or one of the other suggestions.

Comment: +1 because in my case, I don't want to change the original collection. I had tried casting the Concat result back to a List<string> without success.  ToList() does the job.